# Action Script 2 Suggestion

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am doing a project which is about interacting, mouse on screen, Hence, I want to do it by using Adobe Flash Pro and Action Script2.
here is the Task:
- a simple animations (for example: that full of spiders walking/jumping from up to down on the screen) 
- once the mouse moves, the animation will Reverse (all spiders animation will reverse back and hide back to the top of screen from the place that the came). 
- if the mouse doesn't move after 60 Seconds the animation will happen again till the mouse move again on the screen (Those spiders animation will happen again).

i have created a Animation Spider "Movie clip" (spider animation going down)
1- what script i should write to make animation reverse? 
2- how can i tell Adobe my mouse is moved or it's not moving, so the spiders animation will happen or reverse?

by the way, I am a very beginner in action script 2.0
i appreciate any suggestion and help *is fine for me to do it in action script 3 too
Thanks.

Comment: Actionscript 2 is kind of old.. Are you positive you don't want to use Actionscript 3?

Comment: I removed the Adobe Flex Tag because Flex has been built in ActionScript 3 and has since version 2.  The ActionScript 2 version of Flex was a server side product costing a significant amount ( >$10K per CPU).  Also; it is very difficult to use Flex inside of Flash Pro.  If you're a beginner just learning; why would you with ActionSCript 2, something that has for all intents and purposes been made obsolete 6 years ago?

Comment: Okay, because i worked with actions script 2 that why i asked,  would like to learn to do it by using Action Script 3 but how can do it in action script 3?

Comment: AS2 is fine, If you haven't used AS3 yet, don't switch to it just because AS2 is old, you'll be in a world of pain when you're managing memory leagks for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. AS2 :)

OK first off I think it would be easier if you would create 2 different animations. One for the Spider to walk down. The other one to walk up. It is possible to reverse a MovieClip but I think if you`re a beginner, stick with the basics.

You need 3 thinks here.

1) Spider Clips. Going down and up.
2) An interval (timer in AS3)

```
var interval:Number = setInterval(spidersComeOut, 60 * 1000);
```

3) Mouse move listener

```
root.onMouseMove = function() 
{
    //swap your spider clips
    //move the spider up again
    //reset the interval with clearInterval(interval) and restart it again.        
}
```

This is a very basic handler for mouse move. 
Hope this will help you a little bit. This is not a complete solution. It will not work out of the box.

One thing at the end. If you are new to AS2 I would recomend to give as3 a shot. It is more difficult to start with, but there are more people out there willing to help with an AS3 problem then with as2.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you were ready to use AS3 here is solution.

I assume you have a separate movie clip containing your spiders animation which you place on the main timeline/stage.

1.place your MovieClip on the stage and give it the instance name of 'spiders'.

2.inside this MovieClip, on the first frame put this code (it will handle revesing the animation)

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

var _dir:int = 1;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEF);
function onEF(e:Event):void
{
    getNextAnimationFrame();
}

function getNextAnimationFrame():void
{
    var frameNum:int = currentFrame + _dir;
    if (frameNum < 1 || frameNum > totalFrames) 
    {
         removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEF);
    }
    frameNum = Math.max(1, Math.min(totalFrames,frameNum));

    gotoAndStop(frameNum);
}

function changeDirection($dir:int):void
{
    _dir = $dir;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEF);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEF);
}
```

3.on the main timeline (in the first frame) put this code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(60 * 1000, 1);
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTime);

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove);

function onTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace("it's time");
    spiders.changeDirection(1);
}

function onMove(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    spiders.changeDirection(-1);
}
```

It would be possible to handle mouse, timer and animation in one piece of code, however the way it's build now is **kind of** OOP, if at some point you decided to build it properly it would be extremely easy to 'rewrite' this code as separate classes.